# Tables gain two extra vertical lines when using subfiles package

Tags: tables, subfiles

I've had this issue for two weeks now and have not been able to come up with a solution or find one online. When using the subfiles package, any tables I make gain two extra vertical lines that border the leftmost cell. This problem does not occur with the individual .tex files that main.tex calls upon, the lines are only present in main.pdf.

Here is a minimal working example. It reflects all the packages I'm using, which are:

- graphicx
- geometry
- float
- asmath
- xcolor
- colortbl
- fancyhdr
- hyperref
- subfiles

I am also using MikTex and TexWorks, and compiling using pdfLaTeX.

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
    \graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{letterpaper, margin=1in}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
    \definecolor{lightGray}{gray}{0.9}
    \definecolor{darkGray}{gray}{0.7}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \lhead{My name}
    \rhead{Some Subject}
    \cfoot{\thepage}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\subfile{title_and_contents/title_and_contents}

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\subfile{section1/section1}

\end{document}
```

**title_and_contents.tex**

```
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}
\graphicspath{{images/}{../images/}}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\centering
\vspace*{1 cm}
\Huge
\textbf{Some Subject}

\vspace{0.5 cm}
\large
A very interesting report

\vspace{0.5 cm}
Lab Report

\vspace{1.5 cm}
\LARGE
\textbf{My name}

\vfill

\vspace{0.33 cm}
\includegraphics[width = 0.75\textwidth]{SCCLogo}

\vspace{0.33 cm}
\Large
A coure number\\
A course name\\
The professor\\
The date
\end{titlepage}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\newpage
\end{document}
```

**section1.tex**

```
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}
\graphicspath{{images/}{../images/}}

\begin{document}

\section{The first section}
Hi, this is some text I wrote for you so I don't post my homework online. That would be a bad idea. 
Anyway, here's a table so you can see the issue I'm having.

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{| c | c |}
\hline\rowcolor{darkGray}
\color{white}\textbf{A quantity} & \color{white}\textbf{Another quantity}\\
\rowcolor{darkGray}
\color{white}\textbf{Its units} & \color{white}\textbf{More units}\\
\hline
1 & 5\\
\hline\rowcolor{lightGray}
2 & 3\\
\hline
3 & 3\\
\hline\rowcolor{lightGray}
4 & 2\\
\hline
5 & 1\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{A table with fake data}
\end{table}

What you should notice is that when compiled on its own, this .tex file has no issue, but when 
compiled as a part of main.tex, two vertical lines are added to the leftmost cell. Thanks for taking 
a look.

\end{document}
```

Finally, here are screenshots of the offending table in case you are unable to reproduce it.

**From main.pdf**

[image: Table in main.pdf]

**From section1.pdf**

[image: Table in section1.pdf]

All suggestions are welcome and thank you for looking at my problem.

~Will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to the most recent version of subfiles, `2020/11/14 v2.2`. The problem you are experiencing is a bug in `v2.1`. The new version is already available in the distributions MiKTeX and TeXLive, as well as from [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/subfiles) and [Github](https://github.com/gsalzer/subfiles). I have verified that your table typesets correctly with `v2.2`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, gernot, I guess the MikeTex console missed it when I checked earlier, installed it manually and it's working now.